# Why must braces ({, }) in a URL be escaped?

Tags: asp.net

What is the purpose of putting `{ braces }` in a url?

Can you please give an example of putting `{ braces }` in a url?

I encoded like the following to make it work in my applications, otherwise I kept getting an error

```
Script = Script.Replace("{", "%7B");
Script = Script.Replace("}", "%7D");
```

Comment: The reason you needed to encode those characters is that only `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._~:/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=` are valid in a URL. Other characters must be encoded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if I want to search Google for this curly brace character?  https://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=%7D

We need this [encoding scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) to pass these types of reserved characters into the web app.

Also, I see you are manually replacing these one character at a time. That is not a good idea, there is already something written for this in the [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapeuristring) class.

Answer (score 5):

There is some explanation [RFC 1738 - Uniform Resource Locators (URL)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt):

> Characters "{", "}", "|", "\", "^", "~",   "[", "]", and "`" are unsafe because gateways and other transport agents are known to sometimes modify such characters ..
>
> All unsafe characters must always be encoded within a URL ..

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing especial about braces in URL and they are like just any other character. Since it does not fall in valid character range, it needs to be encoded